# Can leiningen see/control dependencies of Java pom.xml dependencies?

Tags: java, clojure, dependencies, leiningen, apache-storm

I'm working on a clojure project that currently uses the latest version of `org.clojure/tools.cli` and in which I wish to begin using `storm`. However, as soon as I add `[storm "0.9.0.1"]` to my dependencies, namespaces which were using the `parse-opts` function fail to compile. My snooping around has led me to the conclusion that `storm` is requiring an older version of `tools.cli` (0.2.x) in a somewhat hidden manner not visible/controllable by leiningen.

The funny thing is

- using `lein deps :tree` does not reveal this dependency, nor does it reveal any warnings about it;
- adding `[storm "0.9.1" :exclusions [org.clojure/tools.cli]]` does not seem to fix the problem.

Looking at the [storm github repo](https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm), it appears that the `tools.cli` specification is in a `pom.xml` file. I have confirmed that forking storm, updating this dependency and using this fork via `lein-git-deps` fixes the problem. However, it's fairly frustrating to have to this.

Is there a way around this? Is there some bug here? Leiningen doesn't document this feature particularly well, at least as far as I've been able to find.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong about leiningen. Storm's runtime dependencies are all under `storm-dir/lib/`, which including `tools.cli-0.2.4.jar`.

There is a workaround, but I'm not sure it will work.

- Download a new version of `tools.cli` jar and put it under `storm-dir/lib/`.
- Move the older version to another place.
- Hope there's not much difference between the two versions and start the topology.

This solution works for some libs, but not all. If not working, any attempt only to change dependency in maven or leiningen will not work either.